# Problemas de acentuação - PHP e HTML

Tags: php, html, acentuação

Ja verifiquei em varios sites, fiz varios testes e ate agora não consegui resolver meu problema quanto a centuação no php.
Eu recebo um pequeno texto em uma variavel, porém quando vem com acento aparece muito desconfigurado desta forma ����o � � .
Ja tentei

```
$variavel = utf8_decode($_POST['texto']);
$variavel = utf8_encode($_POST['texto']);
$variavel = mb_convert_encoding($_POST['texto'], "Windows-1252", "UTF-8");
```

no html head

```
 <meta charset="UTF-8"> e <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

e no php ja tentei

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

Mas não estou conseguindo soluição, não quero tirar os acentos, pois já achei função que o faz, quero apenas que acentuação saia correta e não assim ����o � �
Alguem poderia me ajudar ?

Comment: Esta variável está vindo do banco?

Comment: não, um texto qualquer digitado em um form textarea.

Comment: poste o código que você tem para que possamos dar uma analisada

Comment: recebo o codigo de um formulario   <div class="row">
   <!--#informações -->
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <label for="communicated">Informações</label>
    <div class='col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 input-group'>
     <span class="input-group-addon btn-default">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
     </span>
     <textarea maxlength="5000" type="text" rows = "5" class="form-control" name="communicated" id="getCommunicated" placeholder="" required></textarea>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

Comment: Dê uma olhada neste [link de como criar um exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) e edite sua pergunta

Comment: envio para outra pagina e recebo com post , $informa = utf8_decode($_POST['communicated']); e quando exibo ele num Echo de um modal, ele sai todo estranho

Comment: Fica difícil ajudar com informações incompletas e espalhadas nos comentários :D

Comment: é bem assim, recebo Informações vinda de um TEXTAREA, mando para uma outra pagina via POST, qdo dou um echo na variavel da outra pagina ele vem desconfigurado.